# How to classify e-mail in Outlook before sending from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've got a macro in Excel that send e-mail through Outlook and it works perfectly.
But in my company they recently added an e-mail classification.
Can I insert on my code?

Example: If send 2.000 e-mails at once, I'll have to click 2.000 times on any of the classification button.

The language is in Portuguese (Brazil), so by order is: Confidential, Reserved, Internal, Public.

Classification:

[image: Example of Classification]

```
    Sub ContatoAtivo()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim xTexto As String
    Dim Texto As String
    Dim X, Y, Z As Integer
    Dim Email As String
    Dim Assunto As String
    Dim Qtd As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Qtd = Planilha2.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

    For X = 1 To 1
        Email = Planilha2.Cells(X + 6, 8).Value
        Subject = Planilha3.Cells(11, 1).Value

        If Email <> "" Then

            Set rng = Nothing
            Set rng = Planilha3.Range("E12:F22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

            Text = "Test"

            With OutlookMail
                .To = "test.test@test.com.br"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = Planilha3.Range("A5").Value & " | " & Subject
                .HTMLBody = Text
                '.Display
                .Send

            End With

            Set OutlookMail = Nothing
            Set OutlookApp = Nothing

            Texto = ""

        End If

    Next X

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's an add-in, right? Can you try recording macro and using it to see what code it produces, if any?

Comment: Well, I think it is! I tried recording macro, but it appears nothing sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These controls belong to the Azure Information Protection add-in. Unfortunately, Office (nor VBA or VSTO) doesn't provide any trivial way for customizing a custom UI or dealing with it. Your options are listed below:

1. Try to use the [CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) method which executes the control identified by the `idMso` parameter. You must find the ID of controls you need to launch programmatically.
2. Ask or find the command which is run by clicking the corresponding button in the UI. Note, you can use a late biding technology for that. So, you could call the method from VBA. Read more about that in the [Walkthrough: Call code in a VSTO Add-in from VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2019) article.
3. Use [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) API. Microsoft Active Accessibility is a Component Object Model (COM)-based technology that improves the way accessibility aids work with applications running on Microsoft Windows. It provides dynamic-link libraries that are incorporated into the operating system as well as a COM interface and API elements that provide reliable methods for exposing information about UI elements.

Anyway, I'd suggest contacting AIP add-in developers.

Comment: Good answer, even though no easy solution for VBA devs! I'd suggest if the method is exposed, then simply make the API call from VBA. But yeah, last resort is AA (should be oleacc.dll or oleaut.dll from memory) . I actually prefer UIAutomationCore.dll these days, although it can be slow if not done right. But it is easier to script IMHO